# Codeigniter gives error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_odbc_driver::get()

Tags: php, codeigniter, ms-access, odbc

my codeigniter script for getting data from access database is using odbc driver is not working when i use query builder, but it's working when i use normal query.

when i use query builder like this,

```
$this->db->get('tablename')->result_array();
```

codeigniter gives following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_odbc_driver::from()

But when i use normal query instead of query builder, it works perfectly.

```
$this->db->query('select * from tablename')->result_array();
```

i want to use query builder. my db is access db and connection is via odbc.

please help.

Comment: Check weather you autoloaded database library in config file. And  all values are properly set in database.php file

Comment: yes all details are correct and database library is also autoloaded.

Comment: Hi, which version of CodeIgniter are you using?

Comment: @SanchitPatil have you found the solution i am getting same error